# OneDrive show old files version online

Tags: windows-8.1, sync, onedrive

I have folder OneDrive on my Windows 8.1 computer. It's synchronized with OneDrive online. I replaced some files in the folder, so I see new versions of these files in Windows Explorer, but if I open OneDrive in browser and open the same file, I see old version.

I know it's synchronized, because when I removed some files from folder they were removed from online too.

How I can get new online version of files? I tried upload them, but still see old version.

Answer (score 1):

To address your title "OneDrive show old files version online", in order to see the older versions:

1. Make sure you are logged in to your Windows account (the online account that can access OneDrive)
2. Go to https://onedrive.live.com/
3. Select "Go To My Folder" or whatever directive there should be along the banner of the website (if it does not automatically take you to your folder)
4. Navigate to the folder within which the file who's older versions you wish to view
5. Right-click the file
6. Select "Version History"

Doing these steps should help you find both the current version AND older versions of your file. Hope this helped.